# Featured Image Not Working when loaded from sub-domain

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I set up a sub-domain for hosting my images for my wordpress site. Everything works fine but the only error I get is when attaching a featured image for a post.

It does not pull or show the featured image that I selected from the media library.

Any help how to fix this?